# Does iCloud+ with custom domain support plus addressing in email addresses?

Tags: email, gmail, icloud-plus

I am considering migrating from Google Workspace to iCloud+. On the email front, I have a domain and I use *"plus addressing"* in my Google managed email addresses. For example, one user account email address is joebloe@mydomain.com, and I use joebloe+tag@mydomain.com to receive emails from some services into joebloe@mydomain.com mailbox.

I'm wondering if iCloud+ supports the +tag syntax for custom domains, similar to Google Workspace or Microsoft365. I've seen some people mention using iCloud+'s aliasing feature to achieve a similar result, but I have too many tags to map them all in this way. I also have a catch-all feature set up, but this would not work for me because I have multiple users on the domain using the +tag syntax and I don't want emails for janedoe+tag@mydomain.com to go to joebloe@mydomain.com - they should go to janedoe@mydomain.com instead.

Answer (score 5):

A simple test from my iCloud email account to myself with a tag ("*myaccountname*+atag@icloud.com") worked as expected - i.e. the test email was received AOK at "*myaccountname*@icloud.com"

So iCloud email handling does conform to RFC2822 (§3.2.4) as one would hope.

Comment: I can confirm that I tested this right now and used filters to move mail into a sub folder and it is working.

Comment: Thank you for sharing experience and confirming on an iCloud.com address. My question though is if I use a custom domain instead of an iCloud address. I like the reference to the RFC2822 but no guarantee iCloud+ will conform to it yet

Comment: I have done another test with my custom domain and, yes, it works. The test was sent to "tagged+test@_mycustomdomain-_.uk" and it was received AOK.

Comment: I've just tested my own custom domain with this and can also confirm that this works, even with catch-all disabled. Message sent and successfully received to me+example@example.com.